# Basic help for reverse engineering for a newbie

Tags: assembly, c

I am a newbie to reverse engineering software.

I am familiar x86 asm language, Linux internals, and c language.

After going through lots of tutorials, I didn't absorb much knowledge.
So, I have started writing my own programs then reversing them again from their binaries.

Is this approach good?

Also if I want to get more knowledge, a better grip on assembly and c, should I use ollydbg or IDA pro for starting?
Please recommend some links or books that would be good. :- )

Answer (score 5):

When I started with reversing about 3 years ago I used the following books:

- [Reversing:Secrets of Reverse Engineering](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0764574817)
- [Practical Malware Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593272901)

Both of these books have some really good newbie related content like recognizing C/C++ code constructs in assembly and introduction materials to various tools (both Ollydbg and Ida Pro). If you are more interested in Ida pro, I would suggest reading [The Ida Pro Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593272898). Also the book [Practical Reverse Engineering](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118787315) has some really nice reviews but I didn't have a chance reading it.

For getting more familiar with Ollydbg I did most of the tutorials from the [Legend Of Random page](http://octopuslabs.io/legend/blog/sample-page.html). I liked those tutorials because they don't just focus on reversing C/C++ binaries but also give you a brief look at tools and techniques with reversing Delphi and Visual Basic applications.

When you get a little bit more familiar with the following, I suggest you to try some crackmes from [Crackmes.de](http://crackmes.de/). There are some great newbie related crackmes there like the [Artur Dents series](http://crackmes.de/users/arturdents).

Comment: I could copy/paste this answer. Exactly the same steps, same books, same websites. Great advice.

Answer (score 3):

Download and read [Reverse Engineering for Beginners](http://beginners.re/RE4B-EN.pdf). It is excellent and free to download. It contains lots of theory and examples you can easily understand. Plus, it refers to all major architectures, x86, x86-64bit, ARM and MIPS. And one more thing. Yes, your approach is good, you just have to gradually start reversing more difficult programs, like self-made keygens and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for more challenges like @ubnix suggested, try looking on the [Tuts 4 You](https://tuts4you.com/) website. In the downloads section there are a lot of reverse-engineering resources, including crackmes, tutorials, tools, and references. One of the resources I used in learning was Lena's [Reverse Engineering for Newbies](https://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.1089).

Comment: The password is in the pop-up :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest: http://crackmes.de/ as a source of problems.  Their problems are graduated from fairly easy to extremely difficult.  In addition to problems, they do maintain a list of solutions (not for all problems though) if you get stuck.